# Apache Ignite Lock Expiry

Tags: locking, ignite

I'm using the Java Thick Client of Apache Ignite. I manually acquire locks and release them afterwards. It might happen for whatever reason that code which releases the lock is never reached and thus the lock would persist in the Grid forever.
Is there a way to limit the time a lock may exist in Apache Ignite? I tried with the created expiry policy but the locks were not removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to use `Ignite.reentrantLock()` instead.

You can close() an IgniteLock (I assume you do not have to own it), so you can "GC" them.

Comment: Please elaborate: why? What's the difference?

Comment: Because, you can `close()` an `IgniteLock` (I assume you do not have to own it), so you can "GC" them.

Comment: Thanks :) Your answer got auto-flagged for deletion, hence my request.

Comment: I can close the regular lock as well as long as I have a reference ot it. Only the creator has a reference. But it might always happen, that the application crashes before. Does the ReentrantLock solve this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, this is a persistent lock, you can obtain it by name later.